# Maps Public API KEY

Tags: android, google-maps

Estou a desenvolver uma *app* que usa o **Google Maps**. Quando eu faço `run` a partir do `Eclipse` para o *smartphone*, o Google Maps não apresenta qualquer erro.

Quando publico a *app* na `Play Store`, o **Google Maps** fica com erro, não aparece o mapa.

Comment: Existe a `keystore` de *debug* e uma de produção. Ambas devem estar registradas no [console](https://cloud.google.com/console/project), em **APIs & Auth > Credentials**. Isso já está ok?

Answer (score 3):

Verifique se a api-key que voce esta utilizando é a versão correta e se ela é a versão de release e não a de debug.

de uma olhada nesse tutorial:
https://developers.google.com/maps/mobile-apps?hl=pt-br